# TMUX: show display-panes while presenting a command-prompt?

Tags: bash, unix, tmux

Does tmux allow us to do this?

What i'm trying to configure is a command-line where you are to enter a pane that you intend to move somewhere, and what's quite unfortunate is that once you hit any key during the "display-panes" display dismisses it. It would be awfully convenient to be able to see the display-panes enumeration of the panes during the entering of the command.

What I'm accomplishing with the command script is to specify a window to join. since tmux does not let us join a pane to the same window that it's already in, I am scripting it to break the pane out of the window. I believe I'll need to use run-shell to script this up, but that's not related to this question of if it is possible to somehow get it to display the pane indices during the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Without this feature it is still possible to get the shell itself to gain some insight into the Tmux context. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/385890/98199). It is a fully functionally sufficient workaround though perhaps not as potentially elegant as a tmux feature tweak.

This setting-up-the-unix-environment task is turning out to be absolutely monumental. I'm gonna be so productive I won't know what to do.